# Using Google Maps to GeoCode and Icelandic address not working?

Tags: google-maps, geocode, google-geocoding-api

With A US or canadian address I can geo code with Google API like this:

```
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=4060 st. Anderson ave,north vancouver, bc,canada
```

But when I pass an address for iceland, I get no results. I tried setting the region to "region=is"

```
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Arnarsmára 2,Kópavogur,201,Ísland
```

Notice how the address is in icelandic completely. Is there something special I need to do?

Using the Google Maps web site I can enter that Icelandic address and it shows me the map nicely.

Comment: See the documentation on [Building a valid URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/#BuildingURLs) those characters need to be encoded.  Where should that address be?  Is it a postal/street address or a "place"?

Comment: Turns out that the name of the icelandic city was gender controlled and google didn't like the gender. Change to i on the end of the name and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icelandic's grammar can confuse Google's Maps. Use the neutral term.